# Join two network interfaces using the same port

Tags: networking, server, network-manager

I have 2 hosts

- one with two network interfaces: `10.0.0.1` and `172.0.0.1`
- second with one network interface : `172.0.0.2`

the two hosts are connected to each other using the `172.0.0.0`

The first host expose one port via the `10.0.0.1` interface let's say 8088

I want the second host to connect to this port without using routing or ip forwarding let's say when I do `172.0.0.1:8088` I automatically get the `10.0.0.1:8088`.

How can I do this?

the `10.0.0.1:8088` is a http protocol.

Thank you.

**Update**

I am very sorry maybe I didn't explaine well my problem.

I have a HTTP service listening only on `10.0.0.1:8088`(network interface) so when I do `localhost:8088` or `172.0.0.1:8088` it doesn't work.

now I want to open a new port on the 172.0.0.1 interface that expose the same content as 10.0.0.1:8088 without changing the HTTP service configuration.

the idea behind this is to be able to use 172.0.0.1:8088 same as 10.0.0.1:8088 without changing the HTTP server configuration.

`ifconfig`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:0a:00:00:02  
          inet addr:10.0.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1450  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:ac:12:00:02  
          inet addr:172.0.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:187 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:137 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:193840 (193.8 KB)  TX bytes:11435 (11.4 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:192 (192.0 B)  TX bytes:192 (192.0 B)
```

`netstat -tulpn`

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50070           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      197/java        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30/sshd         
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.1:8088           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      598/java        
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.1:8030           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      598/java        
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.1:8031           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      598/java        
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.1:8032           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      598/java        
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.1:8033           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      598/java        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:43077        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.1:9000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      197/java        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50090           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      414/java        
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      30/sshd         
udp        0      0 127.0.0.11:35495        0.0.0.0:*                           -
```

Comment: 172.0.0.1 and 172.0.0.2 are both public IP ranges.  10.0.0.0/8 is a private IP range.  They don't communicate properly with each other without some chaotic routing rules.

Comment: DO me a favor though, on the system with 10.0.0.1, check netstat -tulpn and add the output to your question as an edit.

Comment: I am not looking to communicate them with each other. I only want to expose a port via the second interface without touching the configuration of the service that expose 8088 port.

Comment: check my *second* comment, I"m asking you to provide information about the port / IP bindings on the system that has both 172.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.1 on it.  Also, do me a favor, and explain what you mean by "When I do 172.0.0.1:8088 I automatically get the 10.0.0.1:8088" - are you saying that whether you access it from 10.0.0.x or 172.0.0.1 on port 8088 you want it to show the same content?

Comment: So I want to expose 10.0.0.1:8088  to 172.0.0.1:port without changing the config of the service listening on 10.0.0.1:8088

Comment: so it's explicitly bound to 10.0.0.1:8088?  If so, you could set up a small nginx server that listens on 172.0.0.1:8088 that would be able to reverse-proxy the requests to the 10.0.0.1:8088 service, but that's why I asked for the `netstat -tulpn` output, because if the 10.0.0.1:8088 service is bound instead to 0.0.0.0 by default, what I suggested above wouldn't work.

Comment: can nginx work for any protocol. is it difficult to setup

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75000/discussion-between-thomas-ward-and-mohamed-amine-ouali).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Specifically** for the service you're discussing here listening on port 8080, it speaks HTTP.  Further, it's only running on `10.0.0.1:8088`.

We can configure `nginx`, which is a web server software, to work on the IP and port binding of `172.0.0.1:8088`.

First, install `nginx`:  `sudo apt-get install nginx`

Once installed, shut down the NGINX service by running: `sudo systemctl stop nginx` or `sudo service nginx stop`.

Remove the default configuration file from NGINX's startup config:

```
sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

Create a configuration file at `/etc/nginx/sites-available` named "8088_reverse_proxy" or whatever name you want to give this configuration file, so you know what it does.  Once you've created the file, put the following text into the configuration file:

```
server {
    listen 172.0.0.1:8088;

    server_name 172.0.0.1;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://10.0.0.1:8088;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
    }
}
```

Save the file once you've entered this.

Then, make a symlink to this configuration file in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/[FILENAME] /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

... making sure to replace `[FILENAME]` with the exact filename you chose for the configuration file.

Then, start the nginx service once this is done with either `sudo service nginx start` or `sudo systemctl start nginx`.

You should then, from any other computer on the 172.0.0.X subnet, or anywhere if this is an Internet address, be able to access the service on 172.0.0.1:8088 by typing `http://172.0.0.1:8088` into the address bar for the other system.